# Python script runs on Pycharm but not using Iron Python on c#

Tags: python, ironpython

I have a script that runs without any problems using Pycharm / Spyder but when I try to run in using Iron Python on c# I get the following error: 'No module named keras.callbacks'

Here is the code I am using to run the script:

```
public string PatchParameter(string parameter, int serviceid)
        {
            var engine = Python.CreateEngine(); // Extract Python language engine from their grasp
            var scope = engine.CreateScope(); // Introduce Python namespace (scope)
            var d = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "serviceid", serviceid},
                { "parameter", parameter}
            }; // Add some sample parameters. Notice that there is no need in specifically setting the object type, interpreter will do that part for us in the script properly with high probability

            scope.SetVariable("params", d); // This will be the name of the dictionary in python script, initialized with previously created .NET Dictionary
            ICollection<string> searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
            searchPaths.Add(@"D:\Projects\xxx");
            searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3");
            searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\Library\bin");
            searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\Scripts");
            searchPaths.Add(@"D:\Projects\SmartTrader\venv");
            searchPaths.Add(@"D:\Projects\SmartTrader\venv\Scripts");
            searchPaths.Add("..\\..");
            engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);
            ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(@"D:\Projects\xxx\Main.py"); // Load the script
            object result = source.Execute(scope);
            parameter = scope.GetVariable<string>("parameter"); // To get the finally set variable 'parameter' from the python script
            return parameter;
        }
```

In the comments it was suggested to add the virtual environment to the search paths, that still did not work though.

I also tried running it through regular CMD and it did not work as well:

```
C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3>python.exe D:\Projects\xxx\Main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects\xxx\Main.py", line 7, in <module>
    import Config as cfg
  File "D:\Projects\xxx\Config.py", line 2, in <module>
    from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

I tried adding the Anaconda paths to its search paths but it did not work.
What am I missing?

Thanks
Amit

Comment: Is it possible that you were using a virtual environment? If so, the default path will not include the installed packages.

Comment: @BramVanroy What do you mean a virtual environment?

Comment: Well... a virtual environment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

Comment: @BramVanroy I did not create the script. How can I check that its not in a virtual evn? I have update the post, I also tried to run it through CMD and it did not work

Comment: What script/command is your pycharm running?  This should tell if you it's using an env or using a different python executable than what C# code is calling

Comment: @BramVanroy D:\Projects\xxx\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/Projects/xxx/Main.py I guess the venv refers to a virtual environment...

Comment: Sounds like you need to add that venv path to your search path above

Comment: @BramVanroy added the following :
            searchPaths.Add(@"D:\Projects\SmartTrader\venv");
            searchPaths.Add(@"D:\Projects\SmartTrader\venv\Scripts");
 and it still does not work

Comment: Did you take out the other ones?  I imagine it does a search for a python executable and goes with the first one it finds

Comment: Might be worth a quick google search to find the best way to use an anaconda env with iron python

Answer (score 0):

You can't run an Anaconda environment with IronPython, sorry.

(You especially probably can't run Keras / Tensorflow on IronPython.)